# Configuring HttpContextMapping or httpContext.id ServiceRegistration property for Sling

Tags: sling

I'm looking to add Sling within my own Karaf Container alongside other web applications I have deployed in Jetty. I have created an OSGI feature that contains all the required sling bundles and I am able to deploy this feature within Karaf without any issue and can make POST and GET requests to Sling, e.g: `POST/GET http://localhost:8181/content/test` without any issues.

The problem is all Sling Servlets & Filters are served from the ROOT '/' context of Jetty. There doesn't seem to be any configuration for Sling to either configure a HttpContextMapping to serve all sling resources from /sling or /cms nor does there seem to be a property to pass a httpContext.id property to all Sling Servlets & Filters registed via OSGI Service Registration.

Sling seems to assume that you either take the launchpad WAR and deploy it within the servlet container at which point the war name dictates the servlet context mapping, eg. you can rename to cms.war or sling.war OR if you take my approach Sling assumes that it will be the only application running within the container?

Does anyone know anyway of configuring sling to run at a given context eg: `http://localhost:8181/sling` when deploying the various bundles within Karaf?